# Mandatory Locking in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, locking, access-rights

In Unix record locking is the technique used to lock the portion of a file for certain amount of time to maintain consistency of the 
data from concurrent access to the file. On this mechanism, Mandatory locking is the technique which is used to lock the portion of the 
file exclusively. If once mandatory locking is enabled to the file, no other process can read or write the data to the locked portion 
of the file. So, to enable mandatory lock to a file, the following is the procedure.

```
Turn ON the set group id bit and turn OFF the group execute bit for the file to be lock.
```

So, what is the need of this process which helds on these group ids and Why I want to do this particularly on group ids to enable mandatory
locking. I saw many of the reference but all of them are tell only the rule instead of why they are implement the rule.

Comment: It's just a semi-arbitrary choice. Directly from [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt): "A file is marked as a candidate for mandatory locking by setting the group-id
bit in its file mode but removing the group-execute bit. This is an otherwise meaningless combination, and was chosen by the System V implementors so as not to break existing user programs."

Comment: @kaylum Still I am not able to understand it. Can you please summarize it.

Comment: There's nothing really to understand. Why does the `open` call take the file name as the first parameter and not the second one? Why is `close` called `close` instead of `throw_away`? Why do you have to follow the above procedure for mandatory locking? They all have the same answer - because the designer of each of those decided that it makes sense to do it that way. Well, to be fair the mandatory locking procedure has an extra reason in that that procedure is unlikely to break existing programs which don't use or care about mandatory locking. There is no other deep technical reason.

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory does not lock exclusively... There are two kinds of locks : **mandatory** and **advisory**. For each kind you can obtain **shared** or **exclusive** locks. Mandatory means that locking policy is enforced to any process using the file in any way. Advisory means that locking is effective only for processes that play the game (use locks explicitly). It is not specified by the interface that locks are mandatory or advisory. In general, they are advisory; but some system lets you control the kind of lock are applicable to files. You just mentioned the way your system is able to active mandatory locking on a given file. Original access rights did not decided any useful purpose to executable bit for regular files nor setgid bit that are not executables or scripts, then implementors are free to use this for specific purposes.